# Login failed for the user when executing query from linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a linked server and i am getting the following error randomly even when the query is executing. Is there anything needs to be done on the Linked Server

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "" returned message
> "Communication link failure". Session Provider: Connection has been
> closed by peer [xFFFFFFFF].  Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
> Login failed for user 'pbi_reporting_read_only'. Msg 4064, Level 11,
> State 1, Line 1 Cannot open user default database. Login failed.

Comment: Please show the code as text not images, please also show the code of the procedure you are calling

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Give more information on the linked server. What is it used for?

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. The linked server is used to query the data from. There are views which contain the tables from the linked server